# jQuery each() and html() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

JS

```
function loadXml() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'test.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(output) {
            $(output).find('name').each(function() {

    $('table > tbody').html('<tr><td>'+$(this).text()+'</td></tr>');

            });
        }
    });

}
```

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="loadXml()">Click Me</a>

<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
        <th>Fav Show</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        //
    </tbody>
</table>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<people>
    <person>
        <name>Sam Uber</name>
        <age>22</age>
        <occupation>Web Developer</occupation>
        <favshow>Batman</favshow>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jenna Taylor</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <occupation>Model</occupation>
        <favshow>Family Guy</favshow>
    </person>
</people>
```

The problem is when I click the link it shows the first name "Sam Uber" and that's it. Instead of showing both names from the XML inside the table body. I don't know why this is since that code is within the each() function.

Even stranger is the fact that it works when I alert the names:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

instead of

```
$('table > tbody').html('<tr><td>'+$(this).text()+'</td></tr>');
```

So I guess the problem is there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `$('table > tbody').html('<tr><td>'+$(this).text()+'</td></tr>');` is replacing all of the html inside of `tbody` with the content given to the function.

You should [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the content instead of filling it.

```
$('table > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$(this).text()+'</td></tr>');
```